# How does SwiftUI dynamically add elements of VStack, HStack, and List?

Tags: swiftui

Take VStack as an example:

```
VStack {
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
}
```

I added 10 Rectangles to VStack. So far there seems to be no problem:
￼
[Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qwa9.png)

However I add another Rectangles then report an error: Extra argument in call

```
    VStack {
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
```

This means that the constructors of VStack, HStack and List can only accept 10 arguments, so I changed the strategy to use nested VStack:

```
    VStack {
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        VStack {
            Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        }
    }
```

This can break through the limitation that VStack can only have ten elements, so I wrote a function to dynamically increased the total number of Rectangles based on user input:

```
private func createRectangles(rectCount: UInt) -> some View {
    func createRectangles(_ i: UInt) -> some View {
        if i <= rectCount {
            return VStack {
                Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                createRectangles(i + 1)
            }
        } else {
            return VStack {
                Rectangle()
            }
        }
    }
    return createRectangles(1)
}
```

Opos!!!
Report an error：
Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest in this case is just to use type erasure, like below (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
private func createRectangles(rectCount: UInt) -> some View {
    func createRectangles(_ i: UInt) -> some View {
        if i <= rectCount {
            return AnyView(VStack {
                Rectangle().size(CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).fill(Color.green).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                createRectangles(i + 1)
            })
        } else {
            return AnyView(VStack {
                Rectangle()
            })
        }
    }
    return createRectangles(1)
}
```