# How To Create a Specific Number of SwiftUI Shapes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to know how to dynamically create multiple SwiftUI shapes (e.g. [Rectangles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle)).

How does one go from something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

To something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            for index 1...10 {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width:100, height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61363838/12299030) can be helpful for case of any number, ie. >10 ViewBuilder limit.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: Yes thanks, exactly what I was looking for! @George_E :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SwiftUI's [ForEach](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) view by providing a range:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { _ in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width:100, height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```